# Octave complex element-wise operations

Tags: matlab, octave

Is there a way to write 'complex' element-wise operations in one line, or do we have to separate them into multiple lines?

For example, let us have this mathematical function: 1/(1+e^-x)
Which I want to calculate for each element on x (x may be a scalar, vector or a matrix).

This is a working code I have written:

```
function r = sigmoid(x)
    r = zeros(size(x));
    r = e.^(-x);
    r = 1.+r;
    r = 1./r;
end
```

My question is - can we simplify it to one line?

Comment: did you not just *try* doing it in one line?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

yeah you can do it by below function

```
function r=sigmoid(x)
r=1./(1+exp(-x))
end
```

this first consider that the exp function calculate exponential values wise element and added by one and finally result divided 1 over matrix element wise and you can get what you want.

Comment: Thanks. so that works because only one '.' is sufficient to declare all actions as "element-wise" or because the exp(-x) is already defined to be element wise? and if the second one is true, then how does 1+exp(-x) works and not 1.+exp(-x)? thanks again

Comment: @Mickey `+` is always elementwise, there is no `.+`. And you could have multiple expressions in there, such as `1./(1+exp(-x.*x))`.

Comment: @Steve yeah you are right. So if instead of the `+` I would have `*` I should have written it as `.*`? So to conclude - the main change so I could fit the function to one line is using `exp()` instead of `^`? Thanks!

Comment: @Mickey `e` isn't defined (in MATLAB at least), but if it were you can still do `1./(1+e.^(-x))`, e.g. `1./(1+exp(1).^(-x))`, although `exp(-x)` is prefered